# how to change VSCode insiders editor language?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just updated the last Visual Studio Code insiders (version 0.10.12) and now, all my application is in French ?!!

How can I return in English ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Originally the only way to force the locale is through the command line option, for example:

```
code --locale=en-US
```

The March release will bring in a new configuration value which you can reach through the command palette (`F1`):

[image]

You can configure the language there:

```
{
    // Defines VSCode's display language.
    // Changing the value requires to restart VSCode.
    "locale":"en-US"
}
```

For more information/context you can view the [feature request here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/4170).

This is available now on the insiders build.